# What is the oldest version of iOS that `setUpWithError()` works with?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, installation, xctest

I'm currently writing test cases and I need to support iOS 11. I was wondering if `setUpWithError()` is actually supported on earlier versions, even though it came out with Xcode 11.4.

Comment: Wish I could help more but you might just test it using an iOS simulator. I noticed that in the project settings | Deployment Info you can choose version of iOS. That way you could just test it out. Not 100% certain that is how to use that setting.

Answer (score 1):

The XCTest framework isn't run by an iOS device, instead it's integrated with Xcode's testing workflow. So, if you're using an Xcode newer than 11.4, doesn't matter in which iOS version you're developing, it will run.